# GraphQL - Get all fields from nested JSON object

Tags: graphql

I'm putting a GraphQL wrapper over an exiting REST API as described in [Zero to GraphQL in 30 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBGzsb2UkeY). I've got an API endpoint for a product with one property that points to a nested object:

```
// API Response
{
  entity_id: 1,
  nested_object: {
    key1: val1,
    key2: val2,
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to define the schema so that I can get this entire nested object without explicitly defining the nested object and all of its properties? I want my query to just specify that I want the nested object, and not need to specify all the properties I want from the nested object:

```
// What I want
{
  product(id: "1") {
    entityId
    nestedObject
  }
}

// What I don't want
{
  product(id: "1") {
    entityId
    nestedObject {
      key1
      key2
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I can do the second version, but it requires lots of extra code, including creating a `NestedObjectType` and specifying all the nested properties. I've also figured out how to automatically get a list of all the keys, like so:

```
const ProductType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  ...

  fields: () => ({
    nestedObject: {
      type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
      resolve: product => Object.keys(product.nested_object)
    }
  })
})
```

I haven't figured out a way to automatically return the entire object, though.

Comment: AFAIK, providing the entire nested object without explicitly specifying its fields is not doable in GraphQL at the moment. It kind of goes against the principle of GraphQL, which aims at providing only the needed / requested pieces of data, rather than providing all data at once. You should seriously consider the motivation for using GraphQL. If you're concerned with mobile data bandwidth, it can be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm just playing around with it for learning purposes. I figured that might be the case.

To me, it makes sense for the top level queries, but not so much for nested objects. In the component, I just want to iterate through everything in the nested object - it seems like if something is added to that object on the server, the client shouldn't need to worry about it. I guess this problem would be more easily avoided if you're using GraphQL as the main api instead of wrapping an existing REST api.

Comment: "it seems like if something is added to that object on the server, the client shouldn't need to worry about it."
Do you mean push-based notification/update (from server to client)?

Comment: No, I meant changing the code - if you add a new key to the object on the server, it seems like you shouldn't need to update the code on the client side as well. All the client wants to do is display every key-value pair in the nested object, it doesn't need to know what those keys are called.

Comment: Fetching data newly introduced on the server side without having modification on the client side is not doable at the moment. If `nested_object` does not have anymore nested object as value, there's an ugly alternative that you can try - defining `nested_object` as an array of strings where first element is the key, the next is its value and so on. This way, the array can be arbitrarily long and your `nested_object` becomes flexible w.r.t. change on the server side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can do the second version, but it requires lots of extra code, including creating a NestedObjectType and specifying all the nested properties.

Do it! It will be great. That's the way to go in order to use GraphQL to its full potential.

Aside from preventing over-fetching, it also gives you a lot of other benefits like type validation, and more readable and maintainable code since your schema gives a fuller description of your data. You'll thank yourself later for doing the extra work up front.

If for some reason you really don't want to go that route though and fully understand the consequences, you could encode the nested objects as strings using `JSON.stringify`.

But like I said, I recommend you don't!

Answer (score 14):

You may try to use scalar JSON type. You can find more [here (based on apollographql)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/scalars-enums/#using-a-package).

- add `scalar JSON` to a schema definition;
- add `{JSON: GraphQLJSON}` to a resolve functions;
- use JSON type in a shema:

```
    scalar JSON
    type Query {
        getObject: JSON
    }
```

- an example of a query:

```
    query {
      getObject
    }
```

- a result:

```
    {
      "data": {
        "getObject": {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2",
          "key3": "value3"
        }
      }
    }
```

Basic code:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
    const { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
    const GraphQLJSON = require("graphql-type-json");

    const schema = buildSchema(`
      scalar JSON

      type Query {
        getObject: JSON
      }
    `);

    const root = {
      JSON: GraphQLJSON,

      getObject: () => {
        return {
          key1: "value1",
          key2: "value2",
          key3: "value3"
        };
      }
    };

    const app = express();
    app.use(
      "/graphql",
      graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        rootValue: root,
        graphiql: true
      })
    );
    app.listen(4000);
    console.log("Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:4000/graphql");
```