# Dealing with special characters from data schema in GraphQL

Tags: api, graphql, schema, special-characters

I am dealing with data which is structured (by a third party) with special characters; like so:

```
"pageFansGenderAge": {
      "current": {
        "U.13-17": 1,
        "U.55-64": 246,
        "M.55-64": 11925,
        "U.35-44": 370,
        "F.45-54": 16443,
        "M.18-24": 8996,
        "M.35-44": 20641,
        "F.25-34": 11687,
        "U.65+": 148,
        "U.18-24": 42,
        "M.25-34": 22341,
        "F.13-17": 177,
        "U.45-54": 415,
        "F.65+": 5916,
        "F.55-64": 12172,
        "M.13-17": 141,
        "M.65+": 6576,
        "F.35-44": 14491,
        "U.25-34": 178,
        "M.45-54": 17979,
        "F.18-24": 5787
      },
```

GraphQL is throwing errors as it can't accept special characters , the full-stop and the hyphen are causing issues. Is there a known way to parse these in to stop the errors? Simply removing all the special characters (obvs) just returns null values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around.

I can return the current data as JSON. Thanks to this stack-overflow answer:

Answer: Use 'scalar JSON' in your GraphQL query

[GraphQL - Get all fields from nested JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059523/graphql-get-all-fields-from-nested-json-object)

[image]
[image]